# How to remove "<" and ">" from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string `<hello>`. I want to remove `< and >`. I tried with `remove()` but it is not working.

```
string str = "<hello>";
string new_str = str.Remove(str.Length-1);
```

But, it is not working. How to remove both `< and >` from the string?

Comment: Don't do this.  Instead, you should correctly escape your HTML output.

Comment: @SLaks With what we saw, we must assume this his problem doesn't scale  up to complete HTML and really ends with the simple "<hello>" case.

Comment: -1 for not even bothering to Google such a simple question

Comment: This is very basic and you only need to look around to find tons of manipulating string examples. If stack to the basics, how to move with the difficult code ? Meaning that if you can not find solution by your self to that easy one, how do you solve file opens, database access, css styles, javascript part...

Comment: If you're hand manipulating Xml (Html), then please ... I'm begging you...find another route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sound like you want [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) method:

```
new_str = str.Trim('<', '>');
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use [trim this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx).  Cool! `"<this > that>".Trim('<','>')=="this > that"`

Comment: It's a vararg, so char[] and a series of chars are the same

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
str = str.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.Replace("<", string.Empty).Replace(">", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Any reason to `string.Empty` instead of `""`?

Comment: Debatable. Way too similar to already existing answers in my opinion. Most people prefer `""`, btw.

Comment: @YoryeNathan and also some people may prefer `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the first and last character, try this:

```
string new_str = (str.StartsWith("<") && str.EndsWith(">")) ? str.SubString(1, str.Length - 2) : str;
```

if all opening and closing characters have to be removed:

```
string new_str = strTrim('<', '>');
```

else

```
string new_str = str.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
```